# connecting QGraphicsview signal to UI slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qwidget, qvboxlayout

I am new to QT and C++ and i have legacy qt-c++ code here which i cant get to work.
Probably its something about the lifetime of the calling objects but hey, but please tell me what i am missing.

In a QT .ui i have various Frames and Widgets containing Frames and Widgets containing a `QVBoxLayout` which we shall call "myLayout"

On click in the .ui file i use

```
myWidget = new mywidget(some params);
myLayout->addWidget(myWidget);
```

where myWidget is declared as `mywidget *myWidget;` in the header file

myWidget is a `QWidget` which internally adds a `QVBoxLayout` to itself and adds a `QGraphicsView`. Using the `MouseReleaseEvent` i emit a signal from the QWidget.

now when i try to connect the signal slot (which i do in cpp file from the ui)

```
connect(myWidget, SIGNAL(mySignal(QString)), this, SLOT(mySlot(QString)));
```

the signals never catch the slot. the slot is public, the signal isnt.

What did i do wrong? Can somebody help. Feel free to ask further questions since i dont really know whats important in c++ questions;)

edit:
the signal gets emitted by `QGraphicsObjects` which themselfs connect to a slot in the `QGraphicsView`. This Slot is called and debuggable. at the end of the Routine an `emit mySignal("...");` is called.

Comment: Did you make sure that the signal is emitted? Does your `connect` statement return `true`?

Comment: Are you sure that you emit signal mySignal? Please, show the code of MouseReleaseEvent. Maybe it does not work?

Comment: when debugging, `emit mySignal("xxx");` is getting called. thanks for the hint that connect can return true, i tested an yes it returns true.

Comment: And what about Q_OBJECT macro? Do you add it in widget declaration?

Comment: the signal gets emitted by `QGraphicsObjects` which themselfs connect to a slot in the `QWidget`. This Slot is called and debuggable. at the end of the Routine an `emit mySignal("...");` is called.

Comment: the class of the `QWidget `has a line "`Q_OBJECT`" first thing after the opening curly bracket.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT

Comment: Hey, after adding an include for the Q_OBJECT everything seems to work. though i thought one include per project should be enough. if you write an answer i can mark it right @KirillChernikov

Comment: It's "Qt", not "QT"

Comment: If you included `QWidget`, you don't have to include `QObject`. Maybe all you had to do was run qmake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to add `Q_OBJECT` macro in your widget declaration. Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT